Why is electron zoomfactor working on development but not working in production?
 let savedZoomLevel = store.get("zoomFactor") || 1;

 webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        zoomFactor: savedZoomLevel,
      },

ipcMain.on("zoom-change", () => {
  const webContents = mainWindow.webContents;
  const zoomFactor = webContents.getZoomFactor();
  store.set("zoomFactor", zoomFactor || 1);
  mainWindow.webContents.zoomFactor = zoomFactor;
});

i have done this but my zoom factor is working properly in development phase but when i build my app and then run the application it is not working i have use electron version 20.1.4 and electron store of ^8.1.0.
i want to have same result as it is on the development build in production build.

TL;DR: It's not possible with the current APIs.

When you set a zoomFactor or zoomLevel, it will actually not apply to your whole app, but to a single domain. So the reason it works in development and not in production is because in dev you use localhost (single domain) while in production you use multiple local files (multiple domains).
To understand better, when you set a zoomFactor it will be saved in the Preferences file of your app (this is Chromium stuff). So for example, if you set a zoom of -0.5 in development, you will have this saved:
{
  "partition": {
    "per_host_zoom_levels": {
      "7076461166223254537": {
        "localhost": -0.5
      }
    }
  }
}

(The id 7076461166223254537 is auto generated and different for every app.)
This work fine because all of your pages are served from this domain/host, and so they get the zoom level. Now, if you do the same in production, you will get something like this instead:
{
  "partition": {
    "per_host_zoom_levels": {
      "7076461166223254537": {
        "file:///[path-to-installed-app]/[html-name].html#/[route]": -0.5
      }
    }
  }
}

This means that the configuration will only be applied to this route, which is the one you are on when you call the setter.
There is a solution... but not really...
Instead of setting per_host_zoom_levels, what you actually need is default_zoom_level:
{
  "partition": {
    "default_zoom_level": {
      "7076461166223254537": -0.5
    }
  }
}

The problem is that currently Electron doesn't expose any APIs to do that. I opened a feature request about this, but there is no way to know when/if it will be implemented.
